# Language on TFS 2017 test template mixed - why?

Tags: tfs

I am not sure if this is a new issue to our TFS2017 Update 3.1 installation or whether it existed since we've updated half a year ago.

But when I open now a test case under a test plan I see that the language in the test template is mixed up.

[image]

My profiles locale is set to German. I am ok with the English text. But the Cyrillic (Russian, Bulgarian, ...?) is strange somehow. It doesn't even go away, when I change the locale to other languages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on other client machines? What language OS do you use or what language do you set for the system locale on your OS? Just try cleaning the caches for your browser, then check it again.

Comment: The issue can be reproduced on any client machine. The Windows Server 2012 has English language. As expected, clearing caches on the client did not solve the problem.

Comment: So the problems should be on TFS server side. Have you ever changed the system locale on the server OS?

Comment: No, the OS locale is always the same and for sure nothing beside from German or English.

Comment: Just try clean caches on your Application Tier server, then restart the server and check if the issue persists...

Comment: Nope, this did not help either.

Comment: Just try to create a new collection and new team project within it to check if the issue persists on the new collection.

Comment: In a new collection it looks good.

Comment: So, it seems you have changed something for your current project template, you can compare your current template with the new one to check if there are any difference, especially for the test case work item type definition file.

Comment: fyi, I upgraded lately to TFS 2018 Update 3. Since then the Cyrillic strings disappeared. But instead at the same place I read now "Histor&y". I compared our customized template with the CMMI template shipped. I found some differences, and a lot of findings of "Histor&amp;y". I am not sure where in the Test Case the history area is defined. I will try a little around. But that seems to be the issue. Thanks!